# Insert to array if value is not present in more arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a forum web app where user can like/dislike post of other users.

I have the following model, representing a Post:

```json
[
  {
    _id:"0002253,
    title:"My first post",
    likes:[],
    dislikes:[]
  },
  {
    _id:"0002254,
    title:"My second post",
    likes:[],
    dislikes:[]
  },
   {
    _id:"0002255,
    title:"My third post",
    likes:[],
    dislikes:[]
  },
]
```

When a user sends a like or dislike, the latter's ID will be inserted into the corresponding array (like or dislike).

Each user can, for each post, insert only a like or a dislike (not both).

The query I used for the insert is the following:

```js
 let vote_result = await Poll.updateOne(
        {
          _id: poll_id,
          $and: [
            { "likes": { $nin: [MY_ID] } },
            { "dislikes": { $nin: [MY_ID] }},
          ],
        },
        {
          $addToSet: {
            "likes": MY_ID,
          },
        },
```

So, theoretically, query should insert MY_ID in likes or dislikes array if and only if MY_ID is not present in either array.

The problem is that query still writes MY_ID in likes array (even if MY_ID is present in dislikes) and vice versa.

Let's suppose now I want to leave a 'Like' to a post:

Phase 1:

```
likes:[]    
dislikes:[]
```

(I am able to like or dislike, it works.)

Phase 2:

```
likes: [MY_ID]
dislikes:[]
```

(I am not able send like again, it works, but I am still able to dislike - it should not allow me to vote again.)

Comment: Just a side design note: considering that the like and dislikes ids are embedded to the post model (it looks like they are), the entry will likely get so big that it might exceed the max mongodb entry size (16MB).
I would suggest you to track on the post just the count of likes (or use aggregation to calculate these, although I prefere embedding) and dislikes and to use another collection to store post likes and dislikes, with such design your problem would also fade away.

Comment: I tried your `updateOne` as written in the question and it worked.  I can add MY_ID (e.g. `AA`) to either `likes` or `dislikes` but only if not already found in *both* lists.
?

Comment: I also tried my query in MongoDB playground (https://mongoplayground.net/) with dummy data and it works... I can't understand why it doesn't work in my Next Js code ...

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting integer/string confusion with `MY_ID`?  The `$nin` will not work as you expect if you are comparing a string to an int, e.g.   `"1234"` vs. `1234`